# django comment system: How to make it more like YouTube's?

Tags: python, django, comments, youtube

I like the comment box at the top with the posts going in reverse order. Comment rating, highest rated comments, all great features, remaining character count, spam flag.

My question is, is there a open commenting system available for Django that already has these features?[image]

Comment: Googling for "django comments" yields http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/comments/ as first result ... :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I suggest Disqus plus django-disqus (http://github.com/arthurk/django-disqus)

Comment: The question is about Django's comment system.